# My facebook app is considered as under 21?

Tags: facebook

I had some issuses getting information about some pages with netgraph, I found that these pages content accessible only if user(app?) is 21 or older.

So my guess is that, my app is considered as under 21.. Is that possible ? Can I change that somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a user access token, because Facebook can't determine your age from an app access token. Some pages are age restricted...